# Redelivery Policy - rabbit mq

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to redeliver a message(if processing of a message fails), after certain period (initial delay) at regular intervals(redelivery delay) and if that message is still unable to processed after certain number of redelivery attempts I wish to send it to a deadletter queue but  am unable to acheive the same

could you please help me.

**Consumer**

```
public class Consumer {

@RabbitListener(queues="com.infy.priority-queue")
public void receivedMessage(String message) throws IOException {

    System.out.println(message);//message format - message with priorty(6)/5/4..
    if(message.endsWith("6"))
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

my configuration is as follows:

```
public abstract class AMQPConfig {
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() 
{
    factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public Queue salesQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable("priority-queue")
            .withArgument("x-max-priority", 10)
            .withArgument("redeliveryPolicy.initialRedeliveryDelay", 6000L)
            .withArgument("redeliveryPolicy.redeliveryDelay", 3000L)
            .withArgument("redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries", 3)
            .withArgument("redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveryDelay",5000L)
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", "")
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-routing-key", salesErrorRoutingKey)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Queue deadLetterQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(deadLetterQueue).build();
}
}
```

Comment: Check out this sample code :- https://github.com/julian-eggers/spring-rabbitmq-dead-letter-queue-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itelg/spring/rabbitmq/example/configuration/RabbitConfiguration.java

Comment: One more example :- https://github.com/cl4r1ty/spring-rabbitmq-dead-letter/

Comment: that looks like activemq properties and not rabbit?